# DJANGO + Google App Engine, Getting Started Tutorial

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm very interested in finding a up-to-date tutorial that shows steps for getting DJANGO running on Google App Engine, anyone know of any such tutorials?

Surprisingly, Google's App Engine DJANGO docs are almost a year old. What gives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a Django fork: django-nonrel project
http://www.franciscosouza.net/2010/08/flying-with-django-in-google-app-engine.html

Comment: definitely the least painful way of using django on GAE; almost exactly the same as otherwise

Comment: Nice write up! Is it possible to use DJANGO authentication with EMAIL & Password versus UserID & password?

Comment: Hi, this link appears to be outdated (404 error), and here's new link: http://www.franciscosouza.com/2010/08/flying-with-django-on-google-app-engine/

Answer (score 4):

since `django-nonrel` is no longer supported and the old tutorials are outdated I dared to write a new tutorial: http://howto.philippkeller.com/2012/12/30/Tutorial-Django-on-Appengine-using-Google-Cloud-SQL/

Comment: I am going to see what else you have written on django GAE your stuff seam the most up to date.

Answer (score 2):

I think this link could help you: http://agiliq.com/dumps/django/docs.html

This is a part of the Django tutorial to use `appengine` instead of Pure Django.

Like in the Django tutorial, we build a poll engine where you can create polls and others can vote for them...

Many thanks to Shabda Raaj!