# A question about Django and Google Apps

Tags: python, django, google-apps

Just wondering about this, is it possible to use Django with the Google Apps API's? I have a small organization that uses Google Apps Education Edition. I was thinking about making a small intranet using Django, and I would love if the first page they saw when they logged in had a few widgets with their email, calendar, maybe docs. I looked over some of the api's, and it seemed that getting the data was possible using the gdata library; but when I looked into using Django, all the search results returned pages about running Django on the app engine, nothing about Google Apps. Just looking for a little guidance, if anyone knew a page or a tutorial where someone had done this.

Thanks!

Comment: Numerous duplicates, e.g. [DJANGO + Google App Engine, Getting Started Tutorial ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544552/django-google-app-engine-getting-started-tutorial)

Comment: My post clearly says I am not interested in getting Django on the Appengine. I want to know about accessing google data api's with Django.

Comment: Oh, must've totally misread this. Sorry about that

Comment: Why did you tag it with google-app-engine when you're explicitly not interested in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. This is not a question about Django and GAE in particular; you may have more luck searching for tutorials on using Django with generic web APIs.

[Here's](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/integrate_web_apis_into_your_django_site/) one I found almost immediately; it uses the del.icio.us API but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. See [this help topic](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=91077).